# Adding multiple Physics constraints to a single object at different points (ie: 4 corners)

Tags: physics

I would like to attach multiple physics basic spring constraints to a single plane, or any object, but it seems that they only attach to the origin of the object. Is there a way to attach it to a vertex or a point?

I tried using hooks, but that didn't work.

[image]

[springs.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwog1fp7vhztpi5/springs.blend?dl=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out your scene and adjusted the physics to be more in line with the situation you asked for.

You used only one **empty** in the **hinges** each, but since they work as a position marker on the first object selected in their constraint options, it was kinda the wrong way.
If you want the **board**(you called it physics) object to be anchored with 4 points, you need to place 4 **empties** on each corner of the **board**, (UPDATE: not needed to parent them, can cause glitches) and use the **board** itself as **first target** in the "rigid body constraint".

Afterwards you set the **empties** as "generic springs" and select the hinge on the corresponding side as second target to the **empties** each. You should now have 2 **empties** on each side of the **board** connected to one **hinge** each.

You can find the set up here:
[image]
(keeping this version available, newer file below!)

I changed one of the constraints to be weaker making the **board** slightly lower on that edge, and the ball rolls down. You can adjust the constraints and tinker to get what you may want it to look like.

Looks like this:
[image]

UPDATE: un-parented the constraint empties and **added** visual connections.
Having the constraints parented under the board caused the glitching.
They don't need to be parented to work, so easy solution, only downside is if you want to move the board, you need to move the constraint-empties as well(select all and you should be fine). May be a bug, that it glitches if parented, don't know.

Here the new version: 
[image]

[image: newer version]

Happy blending.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the bottom left point so glitchy? Next step is to draw connecting lines as springs so it doesn't look like it's hanging in the air.

Comment: Yeah, would sure make it look better if you add some beveled lines to visualize the constraints. And i'm not quite sure what you mean with bottom left and glitchy, i set the values for the bottom right (looking at the picture) weaker to point out the difference of effect the springs have that way. Generally increase the rigid body solver iterations to get a more smooth behavior.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/21xWiYC This is what im seeing in my Blender 2.81a

Comment: I went over it once more and adjusted it to avoid the glitching, little bonus added as well ;)
Check the new version.

Comment: Looks great, I see you used hooks for the wires. As much as I appreciate you doing the project, I'd like to learn how it's done :) I'll try to figure out how to make them into coil springs.

Comment: I still don't understand how the 4 point hinges work, from what it looks like it they are still connected to the center vertex, just offset to the corners? https://imgur.com/a/pk6xlZg I wonder what im doing wrong, trying to recreate this from scratch https://imgur.com/a/lbvw1jH.

Comment: There are 4 anchor empties that are only used for the hooks to fix the wires, those empties are parented and thus create the link to the board. While the 4 constraint empties do not need to be parented to the board (results in glitches if they are). They do though need to be placed on their locations corresponding to the board, after which you have to make sure their first target is the board, and second is the hinge. That's how i build it and it worked. The lines connecting to the origin of the board are just visualizing that the constraints or hooks target the board.

Comment: Without more details then just the pictures of the connections, but not their settings in the constraints, it's rather hard to figure out where the problem may be with the new approach you made. The second picture looks more in line with the setup, the constraint empties would stay where they are as they are not parented. While the object (plane there) would react to the ball. I made the constraints invisible, but if you activated the constraints in the file i added to the answer last, you'd see the same.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add empties as constraints manually, also i don't understand the difference between object>connect and adding the rigid body constraints directly in the physics properties tab, one seems to add empties (xyz) and the other directly attaches to the object. This is the blender file im trying again: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/pB0RVyk0/ I assume that the 4 constraints in the corners should move with the object as they should be affixed to the corners, instead of floating during the animation.

Comment: Aside from the hinge object (cube) that you made a constraint too (not needed), all looks fine. The constraint empties will float if not parented to the board (cube.002). You can parent them, but then they glitch around. If that affects the simulation i do not know, but since the simulation works with the constraints not parented and hidden, i went with that solution. Adding empties as constraints is just adding an empty to your scene and then going in its physics properties to activate and configure it as "Rigid Body Constraint". The Object>Connect i can't seem to find though.

Comment: Object>Rigid Body>Connect  https://imgur.com/a/YQSmtiU

Comment: Using "Connect" while 2 objects are selected creates an empty that works in the same way as when manually doing so. Adding a constraint on an rigid body object (means the rigid body becomes a constraint itself) though makes the spring, hinge or whatever type of constraint you make use the position and rotation aka origin for it's functionality. Thus using empties is the only way to create 4 or more anchor points to an rigid body object like you asked for. As using the object itself would only make it possible to use the origin positioned in a corner to cover for 1 of the 4.